# onclick: picture does not change

Tags: javascript, image, random

My goal is to randomly change an image by clicking on a button. I have found a snippet that does that but I wanted to train my skills and work my way through it, this is what I got so far:

1. When I click the button, with the variable on line 11, nothing happens, but when I put the URL instead of the variable (copied from the console from line 22), it goes to the according picture. I don't get it...
2. When my "imageCount" is full, I get an error

```js
var imageCount = [];
var image = ["img/01.jpg", "img/02.jpg", "img/03.jpeg", "img/04.jpeg"];

function changeImage() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length);
  var imageNumber = "\"url('" + image[rand] + "')\""


  if (imageCount.indexOf(rand) === -1) {
    imageCount.push(rand);
    document.getElementById("imageWrapper").style.backgroundImage = imageNumber;

  } else if (imageCount.length === image.length) {
    imageCount = 0;
  } else {
    changeImage();
  }
  console.log(imageNumber);
  console.log(imageCount.indexOf(rand));
  console.log(image[rand]);
  console.log(imageCount);


}
```

```html
<link href="./style/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button class="button" onclick="changeImage()">Next Pic</button>
  </div>

  <div id="imageWrapper">
    <!--<img src="./img/02.jpg" alt="" id="random">-->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Picture: Console and Error message]

Comment: you are chaging `imageCount ` to 0 so it's no more an array and you can no more apply indexOf. To avoid this, simply add you console.log at the beginning

Comment: if you want to reset `imageCount` just do `imageCount = [];`

Comment: Thank you, with the imageCount set to [] instead of 0, the Error is gone. But the problem, that nothing happens when i click the button, is still there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things stop your demo code from working:

- `#imageWrapper` has no height, so the image is not displayed (probably only because your page's CSS is missing)
- You reset the `imageCount` variable to `0` instead of `[]`

```js
var imageCount = [];
var image = ["//baconmockup.com/300/199/", "//baconmockup.com/300/200/", "//baconmockup.com/300/201/", "//baconmockup.com/300/202/"];

function changeImage() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length);
  var imageNumber = "url('" + image[rand] + "')"


  if (imageCount.indexOf(rand) === -1) {
    imageCount.push(rand);
    document.getElementById("imageWrapper").style.backgroundImage = imageNumber;

  }

  else if (imageCount.length === image.length) {
    imageCount = [];
  }

  else {
    changeImage();
  }
  console.log(imageNumber);
  console.log(imageCount.indexOf(rand));
  console.log(image[rand]);
  console.log(imageCount);


}
```

```css
#imageWrapper {
  height: 200px;
  outline: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button class="button" onclick="changeImage()">Next Pic</button>
  </div>

  <div id="imageWrapper">
    <!--<img src="./img/02.jpg" alt="" id="random">-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not posted my css. I do have a height. It's 75vh. When I'm loading the page, the background-image with the URL, set in the CSS is shown. (Seen in the picture)

Comment: But is this way of doing it ok?

Comment: It's working and don't see anything "wrong" - so yeah, it's ok. :)